# Netbeans 11.3 - all projects are broken

Tags: java, javafx, netbeans

I have downloaded NetBeans and Java 13 for Windows OS, 3 days ago (just started learning coding so very new to this) and it worked fine for 2 days but today all the projects i've created are now broken. When I go to start a new project, it says  feature is not yet enabled but when i click through to activate it,i get a message saying "Not all  requested modules can be enabled."
[Error message when i try to open a new project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCk3S.png)

I've checked online for fixes and done the checking/changing of location in the netbeans.conf file, I uninstalled and re-installed both Netbeans and Java 13, also tried to install Java 8 to try with a previous version and it still doesn't work.

Does anyone have any ideas of what else could be the problem? i have been trying to fix this for hours so any help would be great!!